# Should I also include string.h even it exists in header file?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding the process of making class in cpp.

If I included string in header file, do I also have to include the same header file in the cpp file, which implements header file?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `<string.h>` in C++... For C++ strings, it's `<string>` and for functions that work with C style ones, `<cstring>`.

Comment: it is not completely clear what you are taking about. Is it `std::string` ? In general you need to include what you use. If some header includes a second header and you do include the first then it is not necessary to also include the second, but sometimes you should... Can you show some code?

Comment: If your cpp file `#include`s a header file, it will implicitly `#include` any headers `#include`d by that header file.    That's how the preprocessor generally works.  (It is possible to prevent that happening, for example, by the header using conditional inclusion, but - unless you have deliberately done that - it won't affect you.  Such things don't happen by default).

Answer (score 2):

If you use a declaration or a definition from a header, then you must include that header. Including a header does transitively include all headers included by that header.

You must never rely on transitive inclusion from a header that is not controlled by yourself (i.e. standard headers or library headers) because those inclusions can change across versions. It is a bad design to rely on transitive inclusions of your own headers as well unless properly documented, as such reliance creates invisible dependencies.

---

PS. `<string.h>` is deprecated in favour of `<cstring>` header.

PPS. `<string.h>` does not define `std::string`. That is in the header `<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

No, if the cpp file includes your header file, then you do not need to include it again. Still, if you do, this should not cause any harm, because of the [Include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).